# Safe string copying over DLL boundaries

Tags: c++, dll, stdstring

I am trying to make a DLL that exposes a certain API and thus wanted to implement a safe way to copy strings over the DLL boundaries. The DLL implementation is very straight forward - all the functions that return string values take two arguments - `char*` and `size_t&`. If the size is big enough I `memcpy` the contents of the string from within the DLL to the given pointer, set the size to the actual one and return a successful return code. If it is not I set the size to what it should be and return an error code. The DLL side is very straightforward.

Now what is more complicated - how to make a nice template function which given a pointer to some function from the DLL would do all the correct manipulations to fill out an instance of `std::string`. This is what I came down to:

```
template<typename I>
CErrorCode GetStringValue(const I& Instance, CErrorCode(I::*pMethod)(char*, size_t&) const, std::string& sValue)
{
    std::string sTemporaryValue;
    size_t nValueLength = sTemporaryValue.capacity();
    sTemporaryValue.resize(nValueLength);
    do
    {
        auto eErrorCode = (Instance.*pMethod)(const_cast<char*>(sTemporaryValue.c_str()), nValueLength);
        if (eErrorCode == CErrorCode::BufferTooSmall)
        {
            sTemporaryValue.resize(nValueLength);
        }
        else
        {
            if (eErrorCode == CErrorCode::NoError)
            {
                sTemporaryValue.resize(nValueLength);
                sValue = std::move(sTemporaryValue);
            }
            return eErrorCode;
        }
    } 
    while (true);
}
```

So I did the initial `resize` because I can't do that after the first call (since then it would erase the content, since the string is initially empty). But `resize` fills the string with zero characters, which kind of upsets me (I mean I know I am going to be doing the filling myself anyway). And then I need the `resize` even after a successful run since if the length was actually smaller I need to resize down. Any suggestions if this can be done I a nicer way?

Comment: I would suggest a different design pattern: instead of passing a buffer and a `size_t &` reference, pass a function pointer, and an opaque pointer. The DLL invokes the function pointer, passing to it the `size_t` required for the string, and the opaque pointer, unchanged. The function pointer takes care of allocating sufficient `char []`, and returning a pointer to it. No need to deal with a clumsy `BufferTooSmall`, and wrapping this into a C++ class becomes trivial.

Comment: Well, but if I know that most of the time all the callers will use `std::string` then I am doing an allocation plus copying when transferring to string. Now I stand a partial chance to fill the value upon the first call thus doing only the internal allocations done in the default `std::string` constructor.

Comment: There's no law that prohibits implementing a function that converts its opaque pointer to a `std::string *`, then sizing it accordingly and returning a pointer to the string's data, and then passing a pointer to this function, and a `std::string`, to your DLL.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis The other probable issue is that you're passing a reference.  Reference parameters are not guaranteed to be implemented the same way across modules.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand that:) I'll consider this, thanks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are implying that the sizes of `size_t` could differ between the caller and callee?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis -- No, it isn't the `size_t`, it is the reference itself.  How are references implemented?  It could be implemented differently depending on compiler switches, compilers, etc.  If you look into the C++ standard, nowhere AFAIK does it state *how* references are implemented, only how they are to behave.  Unless you can guarantee that all your apps are built the same way as the DLL (same options), you shouldn't pass reference parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using DLLs, my understanding is that you are on Windows, so I'm going to suggest a Windows-specific solution.

Well, the problem of safely passing string across module boundaries has already been solved on Windows by COM memory allocator and **`BSTR`**.

So, instead of passing a string pointer and a size pointer, and check if the caller's allocated buffer is large enough, and if not return the required size, etc. it seems much simpler to me to just return `BSTR`s from the DLL.

`BSTR`s are allocated using a COM allocator, and so you can allocate them and free them across *different* module boundaries.

There are also nice C++ wrapper classes around a `BSTR`, e.g. **`_bstr_t`** or ATL's **`CComBSTR`**. You can use those at the caller's site.

Once you have a `BSTR` instance, possibly properly wrapped in a convenient RAII wrapper at the caller's site, you can easily convert it to a `std::wstring`.

Or, if you want to use the Unicode UTF-8 encoding and `std::string`, you can convert from the `BSTR`'s native UTF-16 encoding to UTF-8, using `WideCharToMultiByte()` ([this MSDN Magazine article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt763237) can come in handy).

Bonus reading: [Eric’s Complete Guide To BSTR Semantics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/12/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics/)

**P.S.**
If you don't want to use the `BSTR` type, you can still use a common memory allocator provided by COM: e.g. you can allocate your (UTF-8) string memory using **`CoTaskMemAlloc()`** in the DLL, and free it using **`CoTaskMemFree()`** at the caller's site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am well aware of COM, but I'm not bound to Windows, there will be a shared object version for Linux as well. So my initial aim was to to this with standard C/C++ techniques.